# Prevent FlipView from scrolling

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

As the title says, I want to prevent the FlipView from scrolling under certain situations. Is there a way to do this? (In C# please!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy. Set

```
FlipView.IsEnabled = false;
```

If the above somehow causes undesired visual state of your controls - you can also set

```
ManipulationMode="All"
```

on any any item inside of the FlipView to steal control over manipulations from the underlying scroll view. This also works on any other controls with a scroll view - like a ListView, GridView or ListBox.

Comment: Setting ManipulationMode to "All" worked =). Thanks! Edit: Actually, I had to set it to "None"... Edit again: Ah ok, actually both "All" and "None" =)

Comment: How do you re-enable flip if you are using ManipulationMode="all"?  Any manipulation mode I'm setting an individual flip view item to seems to prevent swiping.

Comment: This is disabling all buttons and textbox inside my flipview.
I have applied manipulation "All" and "All,None" both but didn't help.

Comment: OK then you might need to subclass `FlipView` and `FlipViewItem`, make it hide the iteration buttons, override `OnKeyDown` in `FlipViewItem` and not call `base.OnKeyDown()` and update `HorizontalScrollMode` on the `ScrollViewer` in its template.

Comment: A simpler alternative might be to move the content of the `FlipView` outside of the `FlipView` and hide the `FlipView`... or navigate to a separate page with same content to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Use "System" mode to re-enable scrolling.

Comment: I came across the same. Well neither of above worked as I wanted to disable manual gestures and have items content interactible. So what worked for me was to find the scrollviewer among the FlipView kids. Just use VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount - first you gonna get Grid, use this on this grid and you gonna get a Border, then on border - gonna get Grid again and finally on 2nd grid - gonna get ScrollViewer. Set its vertical and horizontal scroll mode to ScrollMode.Disabled. Yay, Microsoft (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻  edit: oh, do that on FlipView.Loaded - no children available before this

Comment: Loaded isn't the most reliable time to access template parts. You should subclass FlipView and do that in OnApplyTemplateOverride. Otherwise Loaded can sometimes come before OnApplyTemplateOverride and you could crash.